# How to get remote git repo tag's commit message

Tags: git

I can have a remote repository's hash by tag `v0.94.9`

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/status-im/status-go v0.94.9
```

How to get the commit message for this tag?
I do not want to clone that repository, just get its commit message for that tag `v0.94.9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a solution that GitHub only (using GitHub APIs):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
url=$(curl https://api.github.com/repos/status-im/status-go/git/ref/tags/v0.94.9 | jq -r .object.url)
curl "$url" | jq -r .message
```

---

TODO: An answer that using [the Smart HTTP(S) protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#_the_smart_protocol):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
commit=$(curl -s --output - "https://github.com/status-im/status-go/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack" | grep -a "v0.94.9" | awk '{print $1}' | cut -b 5- -)
# need help for pack-protocol implementation with curl
```